# How to attach Datetime concentation on Django migration file names

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

When I run :

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

the generated migration files concatenate the model and field name together, but me I want to concatatenate Datetime on the file name generated.

For example this is what I get, which I don't want :

[image]

But I want something like this :

[image]

This is my model :

```
class Assessment(AllProcess, models.Model):

  
   

    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        verbose_name=_('Category'), related_name='category')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number_of_questions = models.IntegerField(
        _('Number of Questions'), help_text=_('Number of questions')
    )
    time = models.IntegerField(
        _('Time'), help_text=_('Duration of the quiz in minutes'))
    score_to_pass = models.IntegerField(
        help_text=_('Required score to pass an assessment in %'))
    test = models.CharField(_('Test'), max_length=100, null=True,
                             blank=True)
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=DIFF_CHOICES)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: What would be the benefit really? Plus you should be able see the timestamp from your OS.

Comment: The benefit is to avoid migration file duplicates or conflicts in the future @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: The migration system is smarter than you think, you really don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know what the end goal is/ why you want to do this. I can think of two options:

- Copy the contents of the `makemigrations` command into a management command in one of your apps. Depending on the order of the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`, you may be able to give it the same name.
- Use `makemigrations --dry-run --verbosity 3` [as described in the command](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ca9872905559026af82000e46cde6f7dedc897b6/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py#L230) to output the migration code to `STDOUT` and redirect that to the file by hand or by writing a bash command to automate the labelling. I suppose rather than copying and pasting the entire file in the first option, you could also write a command that calls `makemigrations` via code and does the file naming.

Comment: The end goal is to avoid future file conflicts
With this solution , can just run this only with added tags  `./manage.py makemigrations` and it works?

Comment: Future conflicts with what? The migration system has that built in as best it can and balks when it can't safely tell if you have a conflict. Not sure you want to subvert that.